# Read from Console and write to file with stdio

Tags: java, stdio

I have this code snippet that reads from and writes to the console. I would like to overwrite the while loop so that instead of writing to the console, the output is written to a .txt file saved locally on my pc. 
I have searched and found a way to redirect System.out to an OutputStream(?) but the problem is that i want a confirmation displayed on the console that the write/output to the file has been carried out. Once i redirect the System.out, everything else i output using System.out is also redirected(?) 
Can you guys help me out here?

```
 class Echo {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    int ch;
    System.out.print ("Enter some text: ");
    while ((ch = System.in.read ()) != '\n') {
      System.out.print ((char) ch);
    }
    System.out.println("Zugriff aufgezeichnet");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `Scanner` to get the input

you dont need a while loop then and i think it is even the better way
the output is explained in the other answer with the FileWriter

i mixed it with the code of nafas:

```
class Echo {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter some text: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Zugriff aufgezeichnet");

    FileWrite fw=new FileWriter(new File("fileName.txt"));
    fw.write(input);
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Nafas answer works too but this is simple and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FileWriter` to write to a File instead of writing to termial.
Make sure, you [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush()) and [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()) the file after you've done with it.

```
class Echo {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    int ch;
    System.out.print ("Enter some text: ");
    FileWrite fw=new FileWriter(new File("fileName.txt"));
    while ((ch = System.in.read ()) != '\n') {
      fw.write((char) ch + "");
    }
    System.out.println("Zugriff aufgezeichnet");
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. The answer without the while is more elegant even though yours works just fine.